# Parameterize Insert...On Duplicate Key UPDATE fails using SET semantics

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update, parameterized-query

I have a database that stores information on clients. I have a unique field for phone numbers called "Phone". I'm trying to use parameterized queries to INSERT into the table, and on a duplicate key, update the clients info. I have quadruple checked the spelling, and everything seems up to par. I keep getting the error "check...for the correct syntax to use near WHERE `Phone`=?"

```
    // These are the fields that we want to Upsert
$fields = "
    `Objectives`  = :objectives,
    `LiquidFunds` = :liquidFunds,
    `UnitNumber`  = :unitNumber,
    `Accredited`  = :accredited,
    `FirstName`   = :firstName,
    `LastName`    = :lastName,
    `Street`      = :street,
    `Phone`       = :phone,
    `Email`       = :email,
    `State`       = :state,
    `Notes`       = :notes,
    `City`        = :city,
    `Zip`         = :zip
";



$updateLead = $dbHandle -> prepare("
    INSERT INTO `Leads` SET $fields
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $fields WHERE `Phone` = :phoneKey"
);
```

And later I am binding the parameters like so

```
    // Bind our parameters to the updateLead query
$updateLead -> bindParam(":objectives" , $objectives);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":liquidFunds", $_POST['liquidFunds']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":unitNumber" , $_POST['unitNumber']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":accredited" , $_POST['accredited']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":firstName"  , $_POST['fname']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":lastName"   , $_POST['lname']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":street"     , $_POST['street']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":phone"      , $_POST['phone']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":phoneKey"   , $_POST['phone']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":email"      , $_POST['email']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":state"      , $_POST['state']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":notes"      , $_POST['notes']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":city"       , $_POST['city']);
$updateLead -> bindParam(":zip"        , $_POST['zip']);
```

This exact structure works perfectly if I change the query to

```
$updateLead = $dbHandle -> prepare("UPDATE `Leads` SET $fields WHERE `Phone` = :phoneKey);
```

I've tried putting everything on the same line, and it threw the same error (just on a different "line number"). What on earth am I doing wrong here?

PS: I'm using PHP/PDO

Comment: Maybe it's to read some manuals about `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was the fact that I had duplicate placeholders in the query. I changed it to this

```
    // These are the fields that we want to Upsert
$fields = "
    `Objectives`  = :objectives,
    `LiquidFunds` = :liquidFunds,
    `UnitNumber`  = :unitNumber,
    `Accredited`  = :accredited,
    `FirstName`   = :firstName,
    `LastName`    = :lastName,
    `Fronter`     = :fronter,
    `Street`      = :street,
    `Phone`       = :phone,
    `Email`       = :email,
    `State`       = :state,
    `Notes`       = :notes,
    `City`        = :city,
    `Zip`         = :zip
";

$updateFields = "
    `Objectives`  = VALUES(Objectives),
    `LiquidFunds` = VALUES(LiquidFunds),
    `UnitNumber`  = VALUES(UnitNumber),
    `Accredited`  = VALUES(Accredited),
    `FirstName`   = VALUES(FirstName),
    `LastName`    = VALUES(LastName),
    `Fronter`     = VALUES(Fronter),
    `Street`      = VALUES(Street),
    `Phone`       = VALUES(Phone),
    `Email`       = VALUES(Email),
    `State`       = VALUES(State),
    `Notes`       = VALUES(Notes),
    `City`        = VALUES(City),
    `Zip`         = VALUES(Zip)
";


$updateLead = $dbHandle -> prepare("
    INSERT INTO `Leads` SET $fields
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $updateFields
");
```

And it worked!

Comment: Same placeholders are ok. Your problem is that this query doesn't support `WHERE`.

Comment: really?.... Why is that, if I may? Does MySQL automatically know which row to update? (That WOULD make sense....). Eitherway, I removed the WHERE clause, as well as the :phoneKey parameter. I'm getting an "invalid number of parameters" error. I'll keep digging. Thanks for the tip either way

Comment: Your `Phone` column is unique - mysql definitely knows what record holds this value

Comment: Thanks alot u_mulder. I really do think that the duplicate placeholders are throwing it off. My parameters match up perfectly and I'm getting an "Invalid Parameter Number" error. I'm going to try something real quick. If it works I'll post an answer. I may delte this "answer" as it is useless to others. (though, your comments are very helpful.